# How to make a powerup force texture with node in 2.9?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I've been struggling with this I've been following these images, but I can't seem to get it right, and I don't know what I did wrong. Also, I'm using 2.92 and the eevee render engine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

here's my nodes and result

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]